# How can we differentiate between translated and orignal post in wpml?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I am making a custom `author.php` file in wordpress and showing post there but thing is it is also showing translated data too, like my web is in **Enligsh** and it is translated in **Chinese** how can i specify the between post which one
is **English** which is **Chinese**.

i'm using it

```
  $courses = get_posts([
                "post_type" => "lp_course",
                "numberposts" => "-1",
                "author" => $guru->ID
            ]);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($courses);
            echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return only posts for the current language you need set 'suppress_filters' of the get_posts function to false.

```
$courses = get_posts([
    "post_type" => "lp_course",
    "numberposts" => "-1",
    "author" => $guru->ID,
    "suppress_filters" => false
]);
```